# Can we use common master page for multiple report in birt?

Tags: birt

Can we use common master page for multiple reports in birt?

I'd like to use common images in my reports and I don't want to change every single report every time I'd like to change an image.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to centralize resources like images:

1. Libraries - Embed the image in a library.  In the report expand the library to show the Embedded Images, right click the image you want to use, and choose Add to Report.
2. Shared Resources Folder - Create a folder to store the images.  Drag an image element from the Palette to the report, set the image to 'Image file in shared resources', and then select the image from the file system.

With both of these approaches changes to the image will automatically be reflected in the report - you don't need to make any changes to the report itself.  I use the library approach because there are report elements that I centralize as well.